# Recreating jQuery `has()` with plain JS. Doesn't work for visited links

Tags: javascript

This code intended to recreate jQuery `.has()` effect with plain JS. The 1st example works fine:

(https://jsfiddle.net/3fdnrsyq/)

```
<script>
NodeList.prototype.has = function(selector) {
  return Array.from(this).filter(e => e.querySelector(selector))
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('.main-container > .analytics:not(#promo)')
  .has('a')
  .forEach(e => e.style.background = 'red')
</script>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="analytics">
    <a>Should be red</a>
  </div>
  <div class="analytics">
    Should not be red
  </div>
  <div id="promo" class="analytics">
    <a>Should not be red</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it doesn't work when I try to use it with visited/unvisited links. Here it is:

(https://jsfiddle.net/1bqdjfrg/)

```
<div class="main-container">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://google.com">Foo</a>
  </figure>
  <figure id="promo">
    <a href="https://ndfkjbnfjkbfjkbf.com">Bar</a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="https://bfkjbfkjfvbjkfsv.com">Baz</a>
  </figure>
</div>

<script>
NodeList.prototype.has = function(selector) {
  return Array.from(this).filter(e => e.querySelector(selector))
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('.main-container > figure')
  .has('a:link')
  .forEach(e => e.style.backgroundColor = 'blue')

document
  .querySelectorAll('.main-container > figure')
  .has('a:visited')
  .forEach(e => e.style.backgroundColor = 'violet')
</script>
```

What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the specs, visited and link access has been disabled.

> It is possible for style sheet authors to abuse the :link and :visited
>   pseudo-classes to determine which sites a user has visited without the
>   user's consent.
>
> UAs may, therefore, treat all links as unvisited links, or implement
>   other measures to preserve the user's privacy while rendering visited
>   and unvisited links differently.

Since you can't access :link and :visited in javascript, for your example, you can still do so in CSS.

```
.main-container > figure a:visited{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: I see, you actively make changes currently, but I should note that `background-color` is valid property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited So, it *should* work (in my opinion).

Comment: @johnc.j., changing the style isn't the problem. The problem is you aren't given access to determine which links have the pseudo-classes of `link` and `visited`. And if you aren't given access to make that determination in javascript, you can't modify its properties. But you can still do so in CSS.